# How to increase upload file size in shiny web application

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server

I have a small application that I deployed as a web page. Uploading of files works fine when I run the application locally. On web page I try to upload a file of 60 MB but it gives an error `413 Request Entity Too Large`. Can any body tell me, how to increase the size. I tried using an xxlarge instance, but it doesn't work either.

Note: `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)` works fine locally not on web.